# How to write condition on client side within gridview itemtemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi could you help me please. I need to write condition on client side within GridView itemtemplate.

Like you can see below but it is not working ...

```
<% if(Eval("item").Contains("keyword"){%>

<img src='<# Eval("imagepath") %>' />

<%}
else if(Eval("item").Contains("keyword2")){
%>
<img src='<# Eval("imagepath2") %>' />

<%}%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a code-behind function to return a boolean.

**ASPX:**

```
   <img src='/path1.jpg' id="img1" runat="server" 
         visible='<%# ShowImg1(Eval("Item")) %>' />

    <img src='/path2.jpg' id="img2" runat="server" 
         visible='<%# ShowImg2(Eval("Item")) %>' />
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
protected boolean ShowImg1(object item)
{
     bool result = false;
     string item = object as string;
     // do your checks and return true or false;

     return result;
}

protected boolean ShowImg2(object item)
{
     bool result = false;
     string item = object as string;
     // do your checks and return true or false;

     return result;
}
```

Comment: it works for me, just change to     protected bool ImgPath(object items)
    {
         bool result = false;
         if(items.ToString().Contains("keyword"))
         {
             result =  true;
         }
         return result;
    }

Answer (score 0):

I modified code Rick Schott suggested in my opinion this way better.

//Client side

```
<img src='<%# ImgPath(Eval("items")) %>' id="Img" runat="server" />
```

//Server side

```
 protected string ImgPath(object items)
    {
        var result = "";
        if (items.ToString().ToLower().Contains("keyword"))
        {
            result = "path_to_image";
        }
        else if (items.ToString().ToLower().Contains("keyword2"))
        {
            result = "path_to_image_2";
        }
        else
        {                
            result = "path_to_image";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src='<# (Eval("imagepath") + string.Empty).Contains("keyword") ? Eval("imagepath") + string.Empty : Emal("Imagepath2") + string.Empty  %>' />
```

Eval("") return an `object`